# Style input after selection from autocomplete list

Tags: css

I'm searching for a way to style input after selection an item from autocomplete. Here is an example (Google Chrome):

[image]

I have already changed default styles for the input, but it seems like they were overridden after selection from autocomplete.

I'm searching for crossbrowser way to style it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A quick Google search provides a `-webkit` specific solution: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/

Comment: @RobertC, it's a good point to start, thank you!